# KMeans in python (framework = django)

Tags: python, django, k-means

I want to use KMeans in Django... my code is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

import sys

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
# Create your models here.

class tabla (models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    comida = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    edad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def datos(self):
        cadena="hola, {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}"
        cadena2="{0} {1} {2}"
        cadena2.format(self.cantidad,self.comida,self.edad)

        #return cadena.format(self.nombre, self.comida,self.cantidad,self.edad,self.fecha_publicacion)
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(cadena2)
        centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        return centroids

    def __str__(self):
        return self.datos()
```

and .. my result is: oh my problem is ...
what is the wrong??

```
C:\TrabajoIA>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 17, 2018 - 04:46:40
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'TrabajoIA.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 17, 2018 - 04:50:53
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'TrabajoIA.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /admin/Gestion/tabla/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 564, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: '__str__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 278, in lookup_field
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 309, in _get_non_gfk_field
    field = opts.get_field(name)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 566, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: tabla has no field named '__str__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py", line 33, in render
    return super().render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 341, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 318, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 309, in __init__
    super().__init__(*items)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 228, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 291, in lookup_field
    value = attr()
  File "C:\TrabajoIA\TrabajoIA\Apps\Gestion\models.py", line 28, in __str__
    return self.datos()
  File "C:\TrabajoIA\TrabajoIA\Apps\Gestion\models.py", line 23, in datos
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(cadena2)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 968, in fit
    return_n_iter=True)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 311, in k_means
    order=order, copy=copy_x)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 522, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{0} {1} {2}'
[17/Dec/2018 04:51:07] "GET /admin/Gestion/tabla/ HTTP/1.1" 500 316834
Internal Server Error: /admin/Gestion/tabla/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 564, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: '__str__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 278, in lookup_field
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 309, in _get_non_gfk_field
    field = opts.get_field(name)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 566, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: tabla has no field named '__str__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py", line 33, in render
    return super().render(context)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\template\library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 341, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 318, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 309, in __init__
    super().__init__(*items)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 228, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 291, in lookup_field
    value = attr()
  File "C:\TrabajoIA\TrabajoIA\Apps\Gestion\models.py", line 28, in __str__
    return self.datos()
  File "C:\TrabajoIA\TrabajoIA\Apps\Gestion\models.py", line 23, in datos
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(cadena2)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 968, in fit
    return_n_iter=True)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 311, in k_means
    order=order, copy=copy_x)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 522, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\kleys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{0} {1} {2}'
[17/Dec/2018 04:51:09] "GET /admin/Gestion/tabla/ HTTP/1.1" 500 316804
```

I see wath ...the main problem is :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{0} {1} {2}'
[17/Dec/2018 04:51:09] "GET /admin/Gestion/tabla/ HTTP/1.1" 500 316804
```

well... 
how to convert that string into a string but of decimal numbers ... something like: [[1], [2], [3]], ... or something very similar to that (this part does not know how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

`KMeans` requires you to pass an array-like object whereas it looks like you're passing strings. You could try replacing

```
cadena2="{0} {1} {2}"
cadena2.format(self.cantidad,self.comida,self.edad)
```

with

```
cadena2 = [self.cantidad,self.comida,self.edad].
```

Which will work assuming the items in the list (`self.cantidad,self.comida,self.edad`) are numeric and not strings.

Comment: I have it defined in the class as "models.PositiveSmallIntegerField ()", for the 3 .. is it okay?

Comment: Yes that will return a result, but what are you trying to find out from clustering the data?

Comment: I have this:  
n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=3         
the correct way above is like this: cadena3 = [[self.cantidad,self.comida,self.edad]]     ........ 
by the dimension, since it accepts 3 (columns), the former was like a single column   ................but. now I see the wrong  n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=3